# How to resolve authentication error when running google script from a sheet simple trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the onEdit trigger to make an API call to tasks.tasks.list. The call works fine when I run it directly from the script editor. However, when I edit the sheet and trigger the onEdit function I get the following error.

API call to tasks.tasks.list failed with error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

How do I provide the authentication credential from the spreadsheet

Tried to create installable trigger but it won't save

[image]

[image]

function OnEdit(event){

```
switch(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName()){

    case "Task List":
      
        addTask(event)
        break
        
    case "Today's Task":
    
        updateTask(event)
        break 

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

Use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.

> Installable triggers, however, offer more flexibility than simple triggers: they can call services that require authorization, they offer several additional types of events including time-driven (clock) triggers, and they can be controlled programmatically.

[image: output]

Comment: Tried to create installable trigger but it is not saving see screenshots

Comment: Please update the post based on what adjustments you have made.

Comment: include screenshots and snippets so we could check. @Sheils

Comment: Make sure to log so that you debug first before posting your findings here. @Sheils

Comment: Ignore lastest comments regarding creating triggers. I was logged into chrome as a different user that was causing the problem