# OAuth 2 token for Google People API query from Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, events, oauth-2.0, google-people-api

I asked a question about this problem previously, but I didn't really understand what the problem is, so I'm trying again.

I want to make a query to the People API, like this:

```
function displayContact() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MAIN");      
  range = sheet.getRange("A2"); //cell contains the name I want to search for
  var query = range.getValue();

  let found = People.People.searchContacts({
    "query": query,
    "readMask": "names,addresses"
  });

  if (found.results) 
  {
    let thisResult = found.results[0];
    let contactAddress = thisResult.person.addresses[0].streetAddress;
  
    outRange = sheet.getRange("A3");
    outRange.setValue(contactAddress); //write the contact's address in A3
  }
  
  else 
  {
    Logger.log(`No results for ${query}`);
  }
}
```

This works fine if I run it from the editor. However, if I call this from onEdit(), the query fails with the following message:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.people.searchContacts
> failed with error: Request is missing required authentication
> credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
> authentication credential. See
> https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
> at displayContact(displayContact:16:29)
> at onEdit(onEdit:22:7)

I've pored over the Google documentation, and managed to create an API key (I think), as well as Googled the problem. I just keep hitting my head against a wall. Would anyone be willing to point me in the right direction as to how to supply People API with an OAuth token when querying from an event trigger in Apps Script?

Comment: I think that this thread is an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67877439 Please use the installable OnEdit trigger instead of the simple trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) At that time, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to another name like `installedOnEdit`, and install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit` in order to avoid the duplicated execution.

Comment: Thank you. I did search for an answer but for some reason didn't find this.

Comment: That's the second time in two weeks that you've saved my bacon. Very grateful.