# OAuth-authentication for container-bound scripts for Calendar API in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to develop an Apps Script Project to programmatically add calendar events to Google Calendar. Because I want to create the eventType "workingLocation" I need to use the Calendar API (not CalendarApp).

My basic code is:

```
const calendarId = 'primary';

const requiredArgs = {
  start: { date: '2023-08-01' },
  end: { date: '2023-08-02' },
  eventType: "workingLocation",
  visibility: "public",
  transparency: "transparent",
  workingLocationProperties: {
    type: 'officeLocation'
  }
}
try {
  var event = Calendar.Events.insert(requiredArgs, calendarId);
  console.log("Location created");
} catch (exception) {
  console.log(exception.message);
}
```

Based on [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/working-hours-and-location?hl=de) source.

**Issue:**

This code is only working when setting up the code as stand-alone AppsScript project.
When I use a container-bounded script with Sheets (e. g. to define the working locations in Sheets and mass update Google calendar afterwards) it shows an error for "calendar.events.insert":

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth
> 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

Why do I need some authentication when working with the Calendar-API in a container-project (in his case with Sheets) but not when working with this API in a stand-alone Apps Script-project?
How do I set up the OAuth-access in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of whether you're using a Bound script or a standalone script, as long as you are signed in to your Google Apps Script editor with a Google account, OAuth is already built-in, so you do not need to set it up.

Comment: To clarify, are you using a personal Google account while testing your script?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I double checked it again. I was signed in correctly. See my answer below: The problem was that I started the script with a simpe trigger, which is not possible according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by SputnikDrunk2 it works in a Bound script or a standalone script, as long as you are signed in.
In my case the script in Sheets has been started by a simple trigger, but the documentation says that installable triggers have to be used for this kind of service. When you set up an installable trigger it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Additional Details

For more detailed information, you may refer to the official documentation that outlines the limitations associated with simple triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

Additionally, to address potential issues that other users might encounter when attempting to use this event type, I want to emphasize that the capability to manage working locations is exclusively available to specific Google Calendar users. This restriction is documented in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/working-hours-and-location?hl=de).

Essentially, the `workingLocation` event type is designed to operate solely for users possessing specific permissions within a Google Workspace domain. Individuals who are testing the `workingLocation` eventType using a personal Google Account will also encounter a `calendar.events.insert` error when attempting to execute the `insert` operation.

## References

- [How to resolve authentication error when running google script from a sheet simple trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877439/how-to-resolve-authentication-error-when-running-google-script-from-a-sheet-simp)